# SQL return COUNT() of rows separated by criteria

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I need to `COUNT()` (or maybe another MySQL function) rows of my query, but I need diferent counts, like this:

What I am getting:

```
   id  | date       | costumer_id
  -----+------- ----+-------------
   1   | 2012-10-05 | 103
   2   | 2012-10-05 | 103
   3   | 2012-10-05 | 103
   4   | 2012-10-05 | 59
   5   | 2012-10-05 | 59
   6   | 2012-10-05 | 90
```

What I need:

```
   id  | date       | costumer_id | count
  -----+------------+-------------+------
   1   | 2012-10-05 | 103         | 3
   5   | 2012-10-05 | 59          | 2
   6   | 2012-10-05 | 90          | 1
```

Comment: Do you want the `Max()` id for items with multiple `costumer_id` ids?  Your data is mixed the `103` has the min but the `59` has the max, which one is correct?

Comment: @bluefeet there is no need for a exact `id`, actually this table columns don't even exist, it's just an example...

Comment: You should provide an accurate example and explanation of what you need then. Because what you provided was not clear due to the data discrepancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple group by query.  I suspect you are leaving the id in the group by.  Try something like this:

```
select max(id), date, customer_id, count(*)
from t
group by date, customer_id
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, `date`, customer_id, COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `customer_id`
```

Comment: I would not promote the selection of columns which are not in the `GROUP BY` just because MySQL allows this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Below query will give you desired results :

select id, date, costumer_id ,count(costumer_id) as c from table1 group by costumer_id order by c desc

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    min(id) as id, 
    date, 
    customer_id, 
    count(*) as count
from tatble
group by 
    date, 
    customer_id
order by 1;
```